# Map list with different types of object but similar attributes

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, casting

I'm trying to map a list with objects with the same attribute but different type:

```
doStuff(list: Array<FilterStatus> | Array<CaseDefinition>){
  list = list.map(value => ({...value, checked: true}));
}
```

I'm getting a typescript error, which I understand because the list has different types, but I'm not sure how to make it work. Any tip?

> : Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: FilterStatus, index: number, array: FilterStatus[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | ((callbackfn: (value: CaseDefinition, index: number, array: CaseDefinition[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has no compatible call signatures.

Reproducible example:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8AoOcuJTAW2AC44BnGKZAcwG4yLsALYbAGtgAEwYAjCBAA2wTEi4BfEiVCRYiFGiy44AIWLdyMBDFkNmrJJyNw+A4WLiSZchSWUlsEJMziYAGQRmBnwAbQBdOABeODCiKloGAHJE4GSAGjt+IVEGLGlGYEUIrm9feHEgkP1ImLiiEzN6OGSm2Uzshzy4AqKSrhV0AFckbBMfOBEIAGUYYfR0AAppYJhQqChMAE8AHnwAPjgAHwJNnd29A4BKQwo4Vb9Yx5gAOmpMMCWAN0xpYbw0SOSyIcFe4N+-2AWXsuScLABcEU12uSiAA

Comment: Perhaps build an interface that lists similar properties? And then build a map a List of that array? (And make the objects inherit from the interface)

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem with the error message.
You can use the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to make such an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd probably want

`Array<FilterStatus | CaseDefinition>`

instead of

`Array<FilterStatus> | Array<CaseDefinition>`

The first is an array of `FilterStatus or CaseDefinition`,
the second one is an array of `FilterStatus` or an array of `CaseDefinition`

Full Example:

```
export interface FilterStatus  {
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;
}

export interface CaseDefinition {
    title: string;
    checked: boolean;
}

const aList: FilterStatus[] = [{name: 'name', checked: false}];
const bList: CaseDefinition[] = [{title: 'title', checked: false}];


function doStuff(list: Array<FilterStatus | CaseDefinition >) {
    list = list.map(value => ({ ...value, checked: true }));
}
```